# How to get Django-Ajax-Selects to work in Django Admin?

Tags: jquery, django, django-ajax-selects

### [Django Ajax Selects](http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-selects/)

Here's what I did, to no avail:

Added `ajax_select` to my `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`

Added `(r'ajax_select', include('ajax_select.urls')),` to `urls.py`

Added this to `settings.py`:

```
AJAX_LOOKUP_CHANNELS = {
    'postal_code': {'model': 'places.PostalCode', 'search_field': 'code'}
}
```

Added this to `admin.py`:

```
class AddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = make_ajax_form(Address, {'postal_code':'postal_code'})

admin.site.register(Address, AddressAdmin)
```

When I tried viewing the relevant page in the admin site and typed in the text box nothing came up. Looking in Firebug, nothing seems to be happening. Presumably because no JS is included; I guess the form/widgets don't include any the way the other admin widgets do.

So, I tried including the media the only way I know how:

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    postal_code = AutoCompleteSelectField('postal_code')

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ['media/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css', 'media/css/iconic.css']
        }
        js = ['media/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js', 'media/js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js', 'media/js/ajax_select.js']

class AddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AddressForm

admin.site.register(Address, AddressAdmin)
```

Now everything gets included, but it still doesn't work. Nothing seems to be happening.

Did I miss a step? Why aren't any JS events firing?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, the problem seems to be that I have to use [the old version of autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/).