# Django - ajax_select widget

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm trying to replace a `SelectMultiple` default widget by the [ajax_select](http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-selects/) one.

I followed the installation guide, here are my files:

**settings.py**

```
AJAX_LOOKUP_CHANNELS = {
    'dubberword' : dict(model='content.DubberWord', search_field='name'),
}

INSTALLED_APPS = (
# ...
    'ajax_select',
# ...
)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# ...
  (r'^ajax_select/', include('ajax_select.urls')),
# ...
)
```

**models.py**

```
class DubberWord(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class Dubber(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  words = models.ManyToManyField(DubberWord, verbose_name='Items')

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

**admin.py**

```
from ajax_select import make_ajax_form

class DubberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = make_ajax_form(Dubber, dict(words='dubberword'))

admin.site.register(Dubber,DubberAdmin)
```

And trying to load the admin page for a `Dubber` object, I get this message

> Caught TemplateDoesNotExist while rendering:
>   autocompleteselectmultiple_dubberword.html,
>   autocompleteselectmultiple.html

Comment: I've been using ajax-select for FK fields in forms which are not in admin. So I tried experimenting since I have the package installed and setup on my dev server. Didn't have a M2M to test on, but I couldn't get a FK working in admin either. It would display the form, but not do any ajax lookups and wouldnt validate even if I put a valid value in. Thought I'd at least let you know I tried, but didn't find anything good. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks. I found a guy which seemed to have the same problem as yourself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872545/how-to-get-django-ajax-selects-to-work-in-django-admin

Comment: @Glide: I am not posting this message because I have a solution for you rather, I myself need some help in using `ajax-selects` There is a field named `arg_default` in `POSTMAN_AUTOCOMPLETER_APP` which has to be given some value as no default exists for it. But it is not mentioned in the docs what kind of value do we have to give. Can you please guide me in this. Any help is really appreciated

Comment: @Sachin Sorry, I finally used [grappelli](http://sehmaschine.github.com/django-grappelli/) for the admin interface, which includes Autocomplete Lookups.

Comment: @Glide: Thanks for the input.. Actually I don't need autocomplete for the admin interface I need it for public pages as well... But I will figure out something. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used grappelli for the admin interface.
It supplies Autocomplete Lookups.